# Обмен данными в  flash

Tags: flash, клиент-сервер

Интересуют все методы обмена данными в flash, ибо столкнулся со следующей проблемой.
При попытке сниффить траффик из флеша к серверу результатом вышло следующее:
Заголовки в плане какой либо информации пустые - простые GET запросы на подгрузку других флеш объектов, однако там, судя по всему, данные отправляются разные. 
Флеш - клиентская часть многопользовательской игры в соц.сети. Из клиента запрашивается информация о чем либо, к примеру, аппартаменты пользователя, НО в HTTP траффике идет просто запрос блока, без каких либо идентефикаторов пользователя. 
Вот и интересует, как, помимо отправки через HTTP флеш может сообщать эти самые идентефикаторы.

Answer (score 1):

Например оформить POST запрос.

[Раз на русском](http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7cfd.html)

[Два на английском](http://scriptcult.com/archives_9/article_442-post-request-data-in-as3.htm)

Пример ActionScript 3:

```
var secondsUTC:Number = new Date().time; 
var dataXML:XML =  
<login> 
    <time>{secondsUTC}</time> 
    <username>Ernie</username> 
    <password>guru</password> 
</login>; 
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.yourdomain.com/login.php"); 
request.contentType = "text/xml"; 
request.data = dataXML.toXMLString(); 
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST; 
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(); 
try 
{ 
    loader.load(request); 
} 
catch (error:ArgumentError) 
{ 
    trace("An ArgumentError has occurred."); 
} 
catch (error:SecurityError) 
{ 
    trace("A SecurityError has occurred."); 
}
```

Comment: Вы, видимо, не поняли меня.
В запросах только GET, и всё. Параметров никаких не передаёт, кроме времени в никсах.

Comment: меня интересуют протоколы обмена и всё остальное,  с чем в плане обмена данными может работать флеш.
в гугле только HTTP траффик мусолят

Comment: Вообще можно и GET запросом передать параметры, с помощью класса URLVariables.

Еще есть способ через сокет передать данные из флеша, но это на PHP многим гуру не нравится.

Comment: Еще есть RTMP протокол. Реализация есть в Red5.

Comment: Всё понятно, внимания к постам вы не прикладываете, жду других, кто сможет помочь.

Comment: Стоп, про RTMP поподробнее можно?

Comment: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol